# Call textinput.py from another python file

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

How can I call textinput.py from another python file? I would like to call it and send a text query as an argument rather than getting the input from the user.
Thank you

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path

Comment: `code` `import importlib.util
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("textinput", "/home/pi/assistant-sdk-python/google-assistant-sdk/googlesamples/assistant/grpc/textinput.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
foo.MyClass()` ... I'm getting errorrs when using the above code. @NickFelker

Comment: I 've used this methods and it is working. I hope it is the correct way . 'code' 'import os
os.system('/home/pi/env/bin/python3 textinput.py --query \'XXXX\' --device-id XXX --device-model-id XXXXXX')'

Comment: I'm glad that it's working for you

Comment: @Nick, Hi Nick, when running the above code (os.system('/home/pi/env/bin/python3 textinput.py --query \'XXXX\' --device-id XXX --device-model-id XXXXXX')' I'm getting Permission denied. Do have any idea why ?

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly, but i'm assuming there's an access error for one of the files.

Comment: When trying to run it from the terminal I get (bash: googlesamples-assistant-textinput: command not found) although pushtotalk works fine. @Nick

Answer (score 0):

I 've used this method and it is working. I hope it is the correct way.
`import os os.system('/home/pi/env/bin/python3 textinput.py --query \'XXXX\' --device-id XXX --device-model-id XXXXXX')`